# Azure webjob accessing third party api could not establish trust relationaship

Tags: c#, azure, ssl, azure-webjobs, azure-cloud-services

In Azure I have a cloud service and a webjob that is trying to use a third party api 'https://api.txtlocal.com/send/' to allow us to send SMS messages from the application.

This has been working correctly, but recently the calls to the api have been failing with the following error:

> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could
>   not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. --->
>   System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote
>   certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Upon contacting TextLocal support, they said some other clients had reported this issue and it was something to do with the Thawte certificate chain of their SSL certificate.

The solution offered was for me to update the Thawte root certificate in our server. (Automatically updated on a desktop pc, so it always works when I run the jobs locally.) So, I remoted to our Azure cloud service VM, updated the certificate in the store, and it started working as expected.

Now however, it has suddenly stopped working again. Microsoft support have informed me that the solution would not have worked for long anyway, as they update the VM every month, and any change I made to certificates would likely have been overwritten.

So, my question is, other than overriding the SSL check, what can I do to ensure the calls to the api work all the time?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the SSL check would not be a clean solution. I would recommend you to write a start up script in Cloud Service which will install the Thawte root certificate on the Cloud Service VM everytime it starts up.

So, you will have to create a script (.cmd/.ps) that installs the certificate. You can bundle this certificate with your app or download from Thawte onto the cloud service VM.

Once the above is done, you can write a startup task, that will call the the above script. You will have to run this in **elevated** mode in order for it to work.

Here is the documentation on how to run startup tasks: [How to configure and run startup tasks for a cloud service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-startup-tasks)

Here is a sample start up task:

```
<Startup>
    <Task commandLine="Startup.cmd" executionContext="limited" taskType="simple">
        <Environment>
            <Variable name="MyVersionNumber" value="1.0.0.0" />
        </Environment>
    </Task>
</Startup>
```

You can have something like this in the file that you pass in the startup task:

```
certmgr.exe -add MyCert.cer -s -r localMachine root
```

Refer this for more information on how to deploy certificate via commandline: [Deploy a Certificate by Using the Command Prompt](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732061(v=ws.10).aspx)

Alternatively, if you want to explore PowerShell then you can refer the documentation for [Import-Certificate](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/pkiclient/import-certificate).

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. This solution however would require me to 'know' when the Thawte certificate had changed, download it and republish my service and webjob again. SInce we are using the Azure environment as PAAS, I do not understand why we have to do anything as the certificates in question do not belong to us and are not part of our infrastructure.

Comment: Agreed. But unfortunately, your application is dependent on that CA certificate. At some point of time, the certificate might be added as part of Windows Update. However until then, this is the solution I can think of. 
You can probably raise a support ticket with Microsoft to get some traction on this.